# increase counter while using exec

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I want to use a counter in a way like the below one:

```
exec
('begin insert into ' + @temp07 + ' (FileID,FileName)
Select aof_id,aof_fileName from PaFi07(' + @partId + ');

sp_executesql @sqlCounter, N'@intCount int output, @intConst int,  @intCount = @intCount output,  @intConst = @intConst 
end')
```

so how can i let the counter work?

any suggestion that the counter work inside this EXEC command
THANX

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `exec` for that:

```
set @inCount = @intCount + @intConst
```

If you want to use `exec`, you would use the name of the variables in the string, not the values:

```
exec('set @inCount = @intCount + @intConst')
```

#### Edit:

For the new question; you would concatenate the values into the string:

```
exec
('begin insert into ' + @temp07 + ' (FileID,FileName)
Select aof_id,aof_fileName from PaFi07(' + @partId + ');

sp_executesql @sqlCounter, N'@intCount int output, @intConst int,  @intCount = ' + @intCount + ' output,  @intConst = ' + @intConst + ' end')
```

If they are numeric values you would need to cast them:

```
... + cast(@intCount as varchar) + ...
```

Comment: could you please re-check the modified question and help

Comment: how?, could you please write it? this is a system sp and it takes a parameters...

Answer (score 0):

You cannot `EXEC` them as `EXEC` runs in its own scope so the variable identifiers have no meaning.

You can instead declare them as `int`s, pass them to `sp_executesql` along with a statement string and return the result as an output;

```
declare @sql nvarchar(256) = 'SET @intCount = @intCount + @intConst'
EXEC sp_executesql @sql, 
    N'@intCount int output, @intConst int', 
    @intCount = @intCount output, 
    @intConst = @intConst

select @intCount 

>6
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not direct"? sp_executesql is the way to pass outer variables into the scope of a dynamic statement

Comment: could you please re-check the modified question and help

Comment: Thats a radically different question.. where is the counter in the statement? what do you want to count? what is `PaFi07`?

Comment: the counter is outside the exec in a while loop, this is just part of the code ;)

Comment: If its outside the exec why do you need to execute incrementing the counter as a string? You will only get partial answers to a partial question ...

Comment: i use the counter in an external loop so i just need the increment the counter only if the condition in EXEC command occures.

Answer (score 0):

There are several errors in your snippet:
First of all, you are declaring your variables as varchar(10), while you are intending to use them as numbers. They should be declared as smallint, int or bigint.

Then you are composing a string using those varchar variables and trying to add 1 to the value stored in @inCount with an addition of the number 1.

Since your variables are strings and not numbers, the + symbols tries to concatenate them.

To realize about your error, first, you should convert the number 1 to a string, writing the EXEC like this:

```
exec ('SET ' + @intCount + ' = ' + @intCount + '1')
```

Once you have done that, just remove the EXEC and assign the string you are concatenating to a new string variable. So:

```
DECLARE @composedQuery varchar(1000)

SET @composedQuery = 'SET ' + @intCount + ' = ' + @intCount + '1'
SELECT @composedQuery
```

You will see a result like this:

```
SET 5 = 51
```

For sure, this is not what you are intending to execute with EXEC, isn't it? :)

The correct solution has been given to you in other answers. I rewrite the full snippet:

```
declare @intCount int
declare @intConst int

set @intCount = 5
set @intConst = 1

SET @intCount = @intCount + 1
--OR
SET @intCount = @intCount + @intConst
```

Comment: Ok, if you want to stand by EXEC, then the solution given by Alex K. is the way to do it. But please, review the declaration of your variables, since they appear to be numbers and not strings.

Comment: could you please re-check the modified question and help